# Can't add Twitter view to the scene

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add a Twitter view so I can see that it's being called, and also that the account is connected, but the Twitter sheet is not there ...
It's on a `CCScene` .(cocos2d)

```
 if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])  
    {
          //we can log here 
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

         [tweetViewController setInitialText:@"message"];

         tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
        {
             if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
            {
             } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
            {
             }
            [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };

        // present view controller
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:viewController.view];
        [viewController presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"NO TWITTER  ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
```

instead of the 2 lines that present the modal view .